# IE9 strange black border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Im facing an strange issue with IE9. I see lots of random black borders in my page even thought they are either box-shadow or simple border: none. Im using windows in Parallel Desktop in my iMac. Is it just my computer or its a common bug?

[image]

Comment: Can we view the HTML for this?

Comment: Thanks. It's not giving me any issues in IE9. Perhaps it's just your computer?

Comment: Also good in IE9 and Google Chrome.

Comment: Then I shouldn't be worry! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Might as well accept the answer I put up, just 'cos. :)

Comment: For sure. Is it to much if I ask you for one screenshot for each page in IE9 ? Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jay,I am not sure but it's look border to me. Do you have tried with border:none.

Comment: In the picture that I uploaded in this question, they are box shadow not border. What do you see?

Comment: I was getting box shadows on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not giving me any issues in IE9 or Google Chrome; it must be your computer.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue that we recently experienced with IE9, and if you are seeing it, there could be a good possibility that many others are too.

If I remember right, I think we resolved just by applying

```
img.class {
  border-style: none;
}
```

for the appropriate classes/id's in CSS - it's probably worth playing around with this just to see if you notice anything change in your browser before ignoring the issue.

Try testing by applying the above to every image on the entire site, then you will see if it is resolvable from this method.

Comment: I added border-style:none; and had the same problem. I think its just my computer.